# How can I access data from a nested dynamic frame to properly format it in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I've uploaded some semi-structed data into AWS glue using a Dynamic frame. From the dynamic frame I just the payload element which I selected by executing the following code in a Glue notebook

```
df_p = df.select_fields(["payload"])
```

I'm trying to convert it to a spark dataframe by executing the following:

```
Spark_df = df_p.toDF()
```

Instead of providing me with a column for each element, I have one column that's titled payload. How can I un-nest the data so I can have x amount of columns where the key is the column name and the value is a row in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for it's called the [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) function. It will unnest one layer.

In your case, you would apply it to the spark DF as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

df_p = df.select_fields(["payload"])
spark_df = df_p.toDF()

exploded_df = spark_df.select(explode("payload"))
```

You might need to apply explode again if the content is nested several times, but that is the way to go. Let me know if it helps.